# GMP Lib : Can we use only one functionality say gmp_printf without Building Complete GMP lib?

Tags: c, gmp

I am just starting with GMP for that I need to check any one function.

I downloaded `gmp-6.0.tar`, extracted it then I used `gmp_printf` in my code .

Now when I open `gmp_printf.c` it has a header file `gmp.h`. But when I search into that extracted folder its not there. So I just want that `printf.c` code to be linked with my native code successfully.

And I don't want complete library to be installed.

Answer (score 2):

The header `gmp.h` is generated when you run `configure` and contains specific information on what settings you configure with. In general it is not a good idea to cut a function from its library. Especially in this case, I cannot see any way you can print GMP types without actually having them defined.

Also note that GMP is LGPLv3 and/or GPL v2.0 and by copying code like this your code must be GPL compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at mini-gmp. It is included in the GMP source as a stand alone, portable SUBSET GMP library. :)

See this mail list thread as reference:
https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-devel/2011-December/002144.html